# extjs Ext.app.Application for custom package

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I am trying to create a package, but it has a bunch of required files and global stores that need to be fetched when the application start. My package used to be part of a larger application, so I had these added to `requires: []` and `stores: []`.

How do we achieve this now that I have a separate package? (Where I no longer have an Application.js file)

**Update**

I have added a Require.js file that contains all the requires for my package. Now I am left with emulating `Application.stores` for creating global stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add dependencies straight to the classes on which they depend (with help 
 [requires](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-requires)). In case this store will have to be initialized manually

Answer on update:

Try override constructor of `Require` class

```
Ext.define('Require', {
    stores:[],
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        Ext.Array.each(this.stores, function (storeName) {
            Ext.require(storeName, function () {
                Ext.create('storeName', {});
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: I would like to avoid having to do this for everything from my package. For views, I can see this being the case, but for stores and utility classes used in my package should not need a require (where my package is used).

Comment: Why? Are these dependencies not part of your package? or do you want to have a single place to connect dependencies?

Comment: Yes they are; but the user of my package should not know what is required to use a component from my package. The component themselves do not require all of their dependencies; they used to be resolved using Application.js. But once I start moving (reusable) components into a package, I am looking for an alternative way to require these dependencies (which are also part of my package) without using Application.js; I am okay with a one liner, but more than that it would make my package less usable (and hard to maintain).

Comment: In my packages I use the way that I wrote above. I described the dependencies of the component in itself. It seems to me that you are trying to use the application approach on package. If your dependencies of package's classes are outside of your package, in my opinion this is bad. Although it all depends on the context. If you created a custom combobox, suppose (treecombo - combobox taht uses treestore), then you should not specify store that you want to connect to it in your package. Do it in the class where you use this component (treecombo). Perhaps I misinterpret your question. sorry

Comment: Most of the my dependencies are from my own package. In your example, if I am providing a custom combobox, I expect the user to just require my custom combobox (view) without knowing what store type they need to require as well. It seems like the immediate solution is for me to add a require for the store in my custom component. I do not have this currently and would like to avoid doing that; I am hoping that I can require all my stores in one place, then instantiate all global stores in the same place. This is what `Application.stores` is providing as far as I know.

Comment: The constructor above is not being called. I even put a `debugger` inside and it does not break.

Comment: That mean you dont create `Require` instance